# Issues with toggle and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/qKMH8/141/

If I remove the .next(), it works of course, but it toggles every answer. I just want the one for that specific section to toggle. Any ideas?

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.question').click(function () {
        $(this).next('.answer').toggle();
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<section class="question active">
    <header>
            <h2>What can I create a fundraising campaign for?</h2>
    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>

    </header>
    <p class="answer">We allow campaigns of almost any nature, however, the following are excluded: Child beauty pageants, pornography, racist content, some religious themes, and illegal activity. If you have a question about what you can fundraise for, please contact us here.</p>
</section>
<section class="question">
    <header>
            <h2><a href="#">What can I create a fundraising campaign for?</a></h2>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-plus-circle"></a>

    </header>
    <p class="answer">We allow campaigns of almost any nature, however, the following are excluded: Child beauty pageants, pornography, racist content, some religious themes, and illegal activity. If you have a question about what you can fundraise for, please contact us here.</p>
</section>
<section class="question">
    <header>
            <h2><a href="#">What can I create a fundraising campaign for?</a></h2>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-plus-circle"></a>

    </header>
    <p class="answer">We allow campaigns of almost any nature, however, the following are excluded: Child beauty pageants, pornography, racist content, some religious themes, and illegal activity. If you have a question about what you can fundraise for, please contact us here.</p>
</section>
<section class="question">
    <header>
            <h2><a href="#">What can I create a fundraising campaign for?</a></h2>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-plus-circle"></a>

    </header>
    <p class="answer">We allow campaigns of almost any nature, however, the following are excluded: Child beauty pageants, pornography, racist content, some religious themes, and illegal activity. If you have a question about what you can fundraise for, please contact us here.</p>
</section>
<section class="question">
    <header>
            <h2><a href="#">What can I create a fundraising campaign for?</a></h2>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-plus-circle"></a>

    </header>
    <p class="answer">We allow campaigns of almost any nature, however, the following are excluded: Child beauty pageants, pornography, racist content, some religious themes, and illegal activity. If you have a question about what you can fundraise for, please contact us here.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: _"the .next() method allows us to search through the **immediately following sibling** of these elements in the DOM tree [...] If the immediately following sibling matches the selector, it remains in the newly constructed jQuery object; otherwise, it is excluded"_ -- http://api.jquery.com/next/.

Comment: I suggest studying the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/). It's a good read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(this).find('.answer').toggle();`

Comment: Thanks , I feel like an idiot now. I knew it was something easy.